# c++ buffer backup failure

Tags: c++, console, buffer

I am working on a console c++ project in which I need to backup a region of the console buffer so I can edit it and revert the changes when done. I came up with this two functions but both have problems since the first outputs an errorcode of **1** `[ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION 1 (0x1) Incorrect function]` and the second one outputs **87** `[ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER 87 (0x57) The parameter is incorrect]` according to [MSDN error code list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681381). I also checked the documentation for [ReadConsoleOutput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/readconsoleoutput) and [WriteConsoleOutput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/writeconsoleoutput) APIs but I'm not able to find a solution.

```
void backupBuffer(PCHAR_INFO buffer, COORD pos, COORD size) {
    SMALL_RECT rect = { pos.X,  pos.Y, pos.X + size.X - 1, pos.Y + size.Y - 1 };
    COORD buffer_index = { 0, 0 };
    BOOL success = 
    ReadConsoleOutput(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),
                      buffer,
                      buffer_index,
                      pos,
                      &rect);
    if (!success) {
        int error = GetLastError();
                    cout << error << endl;
    }
}

void setBuffer(PCHAR_INFO buffer, COORD pos, COORD size) {
    SMALL_RECT rect = { pos.X,  pos.Y, pos.X + size.X - 1, pos.Y + size.Y - 1 };
    COORD buffer_index = { 0, 0 };
    BOOL success =
    WriteConsoleOutput(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),
                       buffer,
                       buffer_index,
                       pos,
                       &rect);
    if (!success) {
        int error = GetLastError();
        cout << error << endl;
    }
}
```

Here's the call:

```
// width = 10, height = 10 and the console
// window dimensions are 30 x 120 but the buffer
// height should be bigger since I'm able to scroll
// down for a while before reaching the end. 
PCHAR_INFO buffer = new CHAR_INFO[width * height];
COORD pos, size;
pos.X = 20; pos.Y = 2;
size.X = width; size.Y = height;
backupBuffer(buffer, pos, size);

// Visual Stuff (cout in that area...)

setBuffer(buffer, pos, size);
```

What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your two functions you have:

```
COORD buffer_index = { 0, 0 };
```

That parameter needs to specify the size of the character info block (in CHAR_INFOs). Right now you are telling it there is no space for the copy.